# C# WPF WebBrowser button click

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm messing around with a WebBrowser in Visual Studio. I would like to create a button inside my main window that, when clicked, it clicks a button inside the WebBrowser. So basically I would just like to know how to press a button automatically using C#.

I have found several pages that tell me how to do this in WinForms, but I really want to do it in WPF and it seems like these things don't work there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve (maybe you can try using another web browser or library for accessing html).

Anyway you can try to call javascript from WPF:

```
object[] codeString = {"alert('Replace this alert with javascript code you need');"};
object result = webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", codeString);
```

Comment: It's pretty straight forward. Imagine you have button and a webbrowser navigated to google. I want to make it so when I click that button, it clicks the search button on google. Only, I just know the class of the "search button", so no id, name, tagname,...